# Left Join in Doctrine and Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi I'm trying to do a Left Join in Symfony with Doctrine.
I allready tried to do it but my attempts failed.
This is the MySQL code what i want to execute.

```
SELECT alben.name,alben.alben_id
FROM alben
LEFT JOIN video
ON alben.alben_id =video.album
```

In the Entity "Video" i defined $album like this.

```
/**
 * @var \Contentuser
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Album")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="album", referencedColumnName="alben_id")
 * })
 */
```

I created a VideoRepository in my Entity folder.

```
$qm = $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select("alben.name,alben.alben_id")
        ->from("alben")
        ->leftJoin("video","video","alben.alben_id =video.album");

        return $qm->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This is the Controller Part:

```
$em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $videoRepo=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Video');
    $videos=$videoRepo->VideoLeftJoin();
```

I get this error 
"Undefined method 'VideoLeftJoin'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy! "
So i tried to do add "findBy" but it didn't work.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you miss "WITH" ?

```
$qm = $this->createQueryBuilder()
->select("alben.name","alben.alben_id") 
->from("alben") 
->leftJoin("video","video", "WITH", "alben.alben_id =video.album");
return $qm->getQuery()->getResult();
```

You have to tell doctrine there is repository :

in yaml : repositoryClass: `AppBundle\Entity\VideoRepo`

in annotation :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\VideoRepository")
 */
class Video
{
    //...
}
```

Make shure you define VideoLeftJoin method as public in this VideoRepository class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell doctrine which repository class to use for the corresponding entity class, otherwise doctrine will use its default one. Modify `Entity` annotation in the `Video` Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="VideoRepositoryClassNameWithNamespace")
 * @ORM\Table
 */
class Video
{
...
```

Where `VideoRepositoryClassNameWithNamespace` is the full path to the repository class. You have to define `VideoLeftJoin` method yourself.

Also, check [Database and Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) and [the Query Builder documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).

Comment: Thanks I will try it.
Allready reading the documention but I don't always get it what they mean :)

Answer (score 0):

The error below simply said

> Undefined method 'VideoLeftJoin'.

then sugested you use one of the predefined method which is

> The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

**TO SOLVE THIS ERROR**

make sure the function **VideoLeftJoin** is in your video repository. Below is an example of how to create it.

```
 public function VideoLeftJoin()
   {
     return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select("alben.name,alben.alben_id")
         ->from("alben")
        ->leftJoin("video","video","alben.alben_id =video.album");
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
   }
```